# Entity Framework and abstract class

Tags: c#, wpf, database, entity-framework, mef

I'm new to Entity Framework and would like to know if, what I want to do, is possible.

I have a class named '**Monitor**' which contains a List of '**MonitorField**'.

Each '**MonitorField**' have a List of an abstract class called 'AMonitoringTool'**

**AMonitoringTool** is provide to allow another developer to create his own kind of field, by inheriting from **AMonitoringTool** in an external DLL.

The main issue is that the application do not know the real type in '**MonitorField**', preventing from saving my objects in database.

I have a **MonitorEntity** with a **DbSet**, but I can't save my Monitor list, I get this error message :

"The abstract type '{...}.**AMonitoringTool**' has no mapped descendant and so cannot be mapped..."

My first thought was to implement the mapping in every DLL that inherit from '**AMonitoringTool**', but I don't how to do it.

**MonitorEntity.cs**

```
public class MonitorEntity : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Monitor> Monitors { get; set; }

    public MonitorEntity()
    {

    }
}
```

**Monitor.cs**

```
   public class Monitor
    {
        public Monitor(string name)
        {
            MonitorName = name;
            FieldList = new List<MonitorField>();
        }

        private List<MonitorField> m_fieldList = null;
        public virtual List<MonitorField> FieldList
        {
            get
            {
                return m_fieldList;
            }
            set
            {
                m_fieldList = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

**MonitorField.cs**

```
public class MonitorField
{
    public AMonitoringTool Configuration { get; set; }

    public MonitorField()
    {
        FieldName = "<label>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Well you need a concrete type to save to the database, you could make the context take a generic type parameter.

Comment: You may have better luck saving something dynamic like this to a document database. You could also serialize your MonitorField items to strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want consumers of this library to have their own implementation of what a `AMonitoringTool` is. I would suggest you create your context with a generic type parameter to let the consumer decide what it is. Something like this should work:

```
//This isn't strictly needed but it will let you force some
//Specific fields for the monitoring tool if you like
public interface IMonitoringTool
{
    string ForcedProperty { get; set; }
}

//Here the type parameter get used for the Configuration property:
public class MonitorField<T> where T : IMonitoringTool
{
    public T Configuration { get; set; }
    public string FieldName { get; set; }

    public MonitorField()
    {
        FieldName = "<label>";
    }
}

//And this is the context:
public class MonitorEntity<T> : DbContext where T : IMonitoringTool
{
    public DbSet<Monitor<T>> Monitors { get; set; }
}

public class Monitor<T> where T : IMonitoringTool
{
    public Monitor(string name)
    {
        MonitorName = name;
        FieldList = new List<MonitorField<T>>();
    }

    public string MonitorName { get; set; }
    public List<MonitorField<T>> FieldList { get; set; }

}
```

So now if a consumer wants a context, they create their own class:

```
public MyMonitoringTool : IMonitoringTool
{
    public string ForcedProperty { get; set; }
    public string MyCustomProperty { get; set; }
}
```

And create their own context:

```
var myContext = new MonitorEntity<MyMonitoringTool>();
```

Comment: Thx for your answer ! I still have an interrogation, your solution work only if  every MonitorField in a single Monitor contains the same type inheriting from AMonitoringTool ?

Comment: Another consumer could create a separate database with their own implementation of the monitor field, but each database would then be locked to that once it was created.