# Entity Framework code first - Derived class not in the same assembly as the base class

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following structure:

- Base Entities (contains abstract MyBaseClass)
- Interfaces
- Concrete Implementation (contains MyClass : MyBaseClass)
- EF project (references all of the above projects)

When I try to enable migrations on the EF project (in order to generate database script), I get the following:

> The abstract type MyBaseClass has no mapped descendants and so cannot
>   be mapped. Either remove MyBaseClass from the model or add one or more
>   types deriving from MyBaseClass to the model

What can I do to make EF look into its references to find my derived class? No Fluent API.

Base Entities assembly:

```
abstract class MyBaseClass
```

Concrete Implementation assembly:

```
class MyClass : MyBaseClass
```

Interfaces assembly:

```
IDbSet<MyBaseClass> WhateverName
```

When I run `Enable-Migrations -ConnectionStringName "EfDataRepository"` EF complains that it can't find derived classes of MyBaseClass.

Comment: Can you provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example ([see](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Comment: Small question, are these set to `public`. Also, could you please provide more context for the above code.; and `IDbSet` might be better as `DbSet`

Comment: yes, public, I just omitted it.

Answer (score 0):

See the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30733420/entity-framework-and-abstract-class). That states that you need a concrete type to save to the database. It also gives an example of the sort of code context I was referring to.